# Shared access level to class in Swift 4

Tags: swift, swift4

Is it possible to deny access to the class for all files except....

So we have three classes for example

```
// file CoreDataStack.swift

class CoreDataStack {   // it's a singleton, where we get managed object context from persistent store }

// file CoreDataManager.swift

class CoreDataManager {   // it has a methods for get entity data using singleton instance of CoreDataStack for get context }

// file SomeService.swift

class SomeService {   // here we do requests and store data with CoreDataManager }
```

So questions is, we have free access to CoreDataStack from our services and another files, but I want to prevent this, I need access only from CoreDataManager

In ObjC syntax we easy can prevent this by "import" statement. Thx

Comment: In Swift, all module files are implicitly imported. Access protections only apply at file and module boundaries, not in between arbitrary sets of files, as with ObjC import statements

Comment: What @Alexander said is correct, however, you could consider adding your CoreData logic to a separate Framework target. Then you could make `CoreDataManager` public and leave `CoreDataStack` as internal.

Comment: @daltonclaybrook Framework target that's what I needed! Big thx!